# Is it possible to only allow CORS from one website only and not directly?

Tags: security, cors

Suppose I have a web application at `origin.com`. When I browse `origin.com` it request cross-site data from `datafeed.origin.com`. I have following written in `.htaccess` of `datafeed.origin.com` `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin origin.com`. Everything works perfectly till this point.

What I need is protect `datafeed.origin.com`. How can I prevent this domain from browsing directly from browser or any other application. Only allow access when cross referencing from `origin.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the origin when setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <origin>[, <origin>]*
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Looking at your post it looks like you've done this, so cross origin requests should fail from other domains

Comment: Yes I have already done it. Now I want to prevent direct access.  Now I have added `if (preg_match("/origin/",$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']))` in `datafeed.origin.com`. I just wanted if there is a better security method.